# PostgreSQL 9.4 to 9.5 upgrade

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

i have a dotnet client application with PostgreSQL 9.4 as my backend database.
When i upgrade my PostgreSQL 9.4 to 9.5 , should i not change anything in the dotnet client application to make it work with the 9.5 version of postgreSQL ?

Please help

Comment: The end of life of Pg 9.5 is February 11, 2021... you sure you shouldn't skip some more versions in one go :D

Comment: I agree with Antti: if you upgrade today, you should aim for 12, not for a version that is going to be unsupported in 6 months.

Comment: As we don't know the SQL queries you are using, it's impossible to answer if you need to change anything. Usually, newer versions are backwards compatible with old versions. If that is not the case it's documented in the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/release-9-5.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, [**do not upgrade to 9.5**](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

[The release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/release-9-5.html#AEN130932) contain a comprehensive list of all incompatibilities that would help you.

At any rate, you need to test your application thoroughly, no matter what.

Comment: Please suggest what version to migrate PostgreSQL 9.4 .  Is it 9.6 or 10 or 11 ? Can we migrate PostgreSQL 9.4 to 11 directly . Do i need to change anything in the client connecting to the PostgreSQL database ?

Comment: v12 or v13. Definitely nothing older than v12. Yes, you can upgrade directly.